# C# Selenium - timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 30.000 (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting the following error message when the process reach the following syntax:

```
        IWebElement OkButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@Name='OK']"));

        OkButton.Click();
```

Error:

timeout: Timed out receiving a message from renderer: 30.000
(Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)

please advice